htaccess redirect folder or empty folder
I have a redirect working fine as follows:
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /file.php?variable=$1 [L,QSA]

So it will send domain.com/folder/foo --> domain.com/file.php?var=foo
But when there is no subdirectory included I want to redirect to a different file like domain.com/folder --> domain.com/file_2.php
Is this possible? How can I order these to detect when no subdirectory name is included? Right now no matter what I try, it simply takes the "blank" value and passes it as the foo variable.

Just put a more specific rule before the one you got. RewriteRule ^folder/?$ /file_2.php [L,QSA]

"Before" here means further up in the file. Directives are processed from top to bottom.

Yes understood. That is what I started with and is not working.

We had it correct in the first place but had an upstream rule that was conflicting.
